# How to develop chat application using WAP in j2me ?

Tags: java-me, chat

I am new to J2ME and i want to develop a chat application using WAP. I want a chat like screen where it shows both the sender messages and the reciever messages. Most of the examples of chat appliction in j2me uses socket connection.But i want to develop using the `MessageConnection` property of the J2ME.

Can any one suggest me how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an application which uses specific port for sending and receiving the messages.
But you need to have the app to be installed on both the phones and the app will use only the regular SMS tariff.